# jsPDF — font so big each letter takes up 3 pages?

Tags: javascript, jspdf

I'm wondering if jsPDF may be the wrong util for me or if I just don't know how to configure it. It doesn't seem to natively handle svgs or any images or html.

I'm hoping to open a PDF and have it look at least remotely like the HTML document or div I'm trying to export. Right now it saves a 380 page PDF with each *letter* taking up about 3 pages.

I feel like I can probably troubleshoot the font size, but I'm more concerned about the lack of formatting or images.

Here is my handleSavePdf method:

```
handleSavePdf() {
  const pdf = new jsPDF("p", "in", "letter"); // I've tried the default jsPDF();
  pdf.html(this.html, {
    width: 7.5, // I've tried no width and other combinations of widths and units
    callback: function (pdf) {
      pdf.save("whatever.pdf");
    },
  });
},
```

[image: Screenshot of PDF in Acrobat]

Comment: What we can't see is your HTML. Could it be that your HTML have some funky css that change scaling or zoom factors?

Comment: try 'pt' instead of 'in'